# Include custom Linked List in custom Hash Table header files

Tags: c++, codenvy

I am trying to create my own Hash table to use my Linked List I have already created. The linked list is in a separate folder and Codenvy won't allow me to use it in a header file.

I have tried relative and absolute pathways like:

```
#include "../LinkedList/LinkedList.h"

#ifndef HASH_TABLE
#define HASH_TABLE
#include "../LinkedList/LinkedList.h"

template <typename T>
class HashTable {
    public:
        HashTable(); // Constructor
        ~HashTable(); // Destructor
        void add (T); // add to the corresponding list
    protected:
        LinkedList<T>[] table; // includes linked lists to carry all data
    private:
        int hashIndex (T); // Finds the index of an element


};

#endif
```

I was expecting that c++ would allow for an array to be constituted of custom objects, but I am probably very wrong. Errors were:

```
In file included from Main.cpp:2:0:
HashTable.h:12:22: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
         LinkedList<T>[] table;
                  ^
```

Comment: `LinkedList<T>[] table;` doesn't make sense. What are you trying to declare here? What are the square brackets supposed to be for?

Comment: If the header could not be found, you would be receiving errors saying so.

Comment: Arrays can be constructed of custom types, but the size of an array must be provided as a compile time constant. This makes them difficult to use in  a hash table because you can never change the  size of the array to adjust the load factor.

Comment: `LinkedList<T> [] table; // includes linked lists to carry all data` -- You need to start creating your own `vector` class then.  If you're going to take the effort in creating linked lists, hash tables, etc. you need to also create the basic dynamic array class also.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
LinkedList<T> table[size];
```

Remember: the size of the array must be constant and known at compile time